# Error:maven-resources-test:twitter_storm_new: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-storm

I'm trying to run a storm topology using intellij. Up until today, the topology ran perfectly fine but today everytime I try to run it I keep getting the following error:

```
Error:maven-resources-test:twitter_storm_new: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
```

Can anyone tell if there is a way to resolve it and how?

Here's my code for the topology:

```
public class AuthorsAndFeaturesTopology {
   public static final String PATH_TO_AUTHORS_AND_FEATURES_FILE="/home/christina/twitter_storm_new/CSV/features.csv";
public static final String PATH_TO_AUTHORS_AND_NEW_FEATURES_FILE="/home/christina/twitter_storm_new/CSV/featuresnew.csv";

public static final String keyword1="#blacklivesmatter";
public static final String keyword2="#germanwings";
public static final String keyword3="#bigdata";

public static void main(String[]args ) throws Exception {
    TopologyBuilder topologyBuilder = new TopologyBuilder();

    //topologyBuilder.setSpout("PROCESS_AUTHORS_AND_FEATURES_FILE", new ProcessAuthorsAndFeaturesFromCSVFileSpout(PATH_TO_AUTHORS_AND_FEATURES_FILE,keyword1,keyword2,keyword3),4);




    Config config = new Config();
    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
        config.setNumWorkers(10);
        config.setMaxSpoutPending(100);
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], config, topologyBuilder.createTopology());
    } else {
        LocalCluster localCluster = new LocalCluster();
        localCluster.submitTopology("Test", config, topologyBuilder.createTopology());
        Utils.sleep(2*10000);
        localCluster.killTopology("Test");
        localCluster.shutdown();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 48):

I just hit similar error with `maven-resources-test:...:java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException` but I haven't found any solution anywhere.

Maven *compile* worked ok, only **build** from IntelliJ was throwing such error.

Tried to:

- maven *clean* - didn't help
- invalidating cache and restart - didn't help
- removing whole .idea folder and iml files and creating project again - didn't help
- change codebase to older - didn't help - reverted
- removing test folder - didn't help - reverted

What solved my issue was **Build->Rebuild Project** (maybe together with some of above)

Comment: It looks like a bug in IDEA. "Build->Rebuild Project" indeed fixes the issue.

Comment: Tried "Invalidate and Restart". Did not help. Tried Rebuild Project. Did help. Thanks!

Comment: Rebuild project help here..!

Comment: Seven years later and "Rebuild project" still helps :-)

Answer (score 21):

I was having that issue too. As @Grx explained , Build->Rebuild Project solved the problem

Comment: Solved my problem, too! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the **.idea** folder after that the error was fixed.